# Phase prediction by cct diagram

Tags: materials, manufacturing-engineering, metallurgy, welding

Can someone please help in finding out the phase proportion of each phase w.r.t time , cooling rate and temperature by using (mathematical model to predict phases from given cct diagram)

> Leblond method

Comment: What models have you looked at so far?

Comment: Additivity rule

Comment: I guess you mean for steels. The actual cct can help with speculating what may result when used with experience,

Comment: I want a mathematical model to predict phase fraction w.r.t. time and temperature for a given cct diagram

Comment: have a look at : https://engineering.stackexchange.com/q/25849/10902